# How to install SharePoint 2013 on Windows 10?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to install sharepoint 2013 in windows 10. Tried with Disruptive Innovations but didn't worked. Is there any other way to install SP 2013 on windows 10?

Comment: Don't. Use Hyper-V on Windows 10 Pro and install Server 2012 or higher and install SharePoint on that. Or use another provider, like Azure or AWS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

At present, there is no way to install SharePoint 2013 directly in Windows 10 machines. Maybe in future they can provide this option.

We have an option by creating Virtual machines under Windows 10 and then to install server OS (2012 or 2016) with SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install oracle virtual box and allocate the RAM more then 5gb and allocate the space more then 70gb and install Windows Server R2  OS.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads